# Updating initialValues prop on Formik Form does not update input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I use a formik form with forward refs like so

#### Form.js

```
import React from "react";
import FormikWithRef from "./FormikWithRef";

const Form = ({
  formRef,
  children,
  initialValues,
  validationSchema,
  onSubmit
}) => {
  return (
    <FormikWithRef
      validateOnChange={true}
      validateOnBlur={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      ref={formRef}
    >
      {(props) => <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>{children}</form>}
    </FormikWithRef>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

#### FormikWithRef.js

```
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";

function FormikWithRef(props, ref) {
  let _formikProps = {};

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => _formikProps);

  return (
    <Formik {...props}>
      {(formikProps) => {
        _formikProps = formikProps;
        if (typeof props.children === "function") {
          return props.children(formikProps);
        }
        return props.children;
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default forwardRef(FormikWithRef);
```

I have some tabs, that update an `easy-peasy` store state `type`, when I select the 2nd tab, I was wanting to update the input value (that initially comes from the store state of `value`) with a Formik form, but updating state `initialValues` specific to that component that gets passed as `initialValues` prop to the `Formik` component.

#### TabsForm.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
import Form from "./Form";
import MoneyBox from "./MoneyBox";

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
`;

const FieldWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 20px 12px;
`;

const TabsForm = () => {
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState();

  const type = useStoreState((state) => state.type);
  const value = useStoreState((state) => state.value);

  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const onFormSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log({ values });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value && type) {
      let filterVal = { ...value };
      /*  here is where I update the input value to be 3000, 
      the initial values get updated and in the `Form.js` file, 
      the console log from here also reflects this update,
      however, the input field does not update? */
      if (type === "Two") filterVal.input = 30000;
      setInitialValues(filterVal);
    }
  }, [value, type]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //   check initialValues has updated
    console.log({ initialValues });
  }, [initialValues]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {initialValues && type ? (
        <Form
          initialValues={initialValues}
          onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
          formRef={formRef}
        >
          <FieldWrapper>
            <MoneyBox name="input" currencySymbol={"£"} />
          </FieldWrapper>
        </Form>
      ) : null}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default TabsForm;
```

When clicking the 2nd tab;

- The `initialValues` state in `TabsForms.js` updates so that `value.input` = `30000`;
- The `initialValues` prop in both `Form.js` and `FormikWithRef.js` also reflect that `value.input` = `3000`
- However, the input does not update, using the `useField` hook from `forimk` in the `MoneyBox.js` component, the `field` object does not have a `value` of `30000`, instead it's whatever the field value was before, why is this?

I have created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-shape-z1ygv) to see all the components used, and console logs to see that the Formik does receive the updated value, but doesn't seem to apply it.

I've been stuck on this for a few days and can't seem to find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want the value of the input to change when you change `initialValues`, you need to pass to the `Formik` component the prop [`enableReinitialize`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean) as `true`.

So, what you need to change in your code is in `TabsForm.js` pass to your `Form` component the prop `enableReinitialize`

```
<Form
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
  formRef={formRef}
>
  <FieldWrapper>
    <MoneyBox name="input" currencySymbol={"£"} />
  </FieldWrapper>
</Form>
```

And in your `Form.js` pass that prop to the `Formik` component

```
const Form = ({
  formRef,
  children,
  initialValues,
  validationSchema,
  onSubmit,
  enableReinitialize
}) => {
  return (
    <FormikWithRef
      enableReinitialize={enableReinitialize}
      validateOnChange={true}
      validateOnBlur={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      ref={formRef}
    >
      {(props) => <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>{children}</form>}
    </FormikWithRef>
  );
};
```

I'm not quite sure how you business logic should work, but here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bogdan-e6sj0?file=/src/Form.js) with the changes above.

Comment: Thank you. Had no idea that prop existed!

Answer (score 0):

( [Solution CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-brook-kc2il?file=/src/Tabs.js))

It's called `initialValues`, so why you expect it to update the form values when you change it? (however you can ask it to do so by using `enableReinitialize` prop, as @Vencovsky mentioned in another answer.)

For binding your desired value (`value.input` in the `easy-peasy` store) to formik input, you can use:

```
const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props);
useEffect(() => {
  helpers.setValue(value.input)
}, [value])
```

it will update the value of the formik input field every time the `value` in store changes.

and for changing the value of the state in store, you can use the way you did it for setting tabs. (using `easy-peasy` store.)

[Run It On CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-brook-kc2il?file=/src/Tabs.js)

On line 49 in `Tabs.js`, it updates the value when a tab is clicked.

On line 19 in `Input.js`, it binds the input value to your store state.

Answer (score -5):

enableReinitialize={true} prop will do the trick for you

Comment: Please take your time to provide a high quality answer. Can you explain why it works and also add a small example? Please see [answer]?